# How to get links from website, not seen in view source

Tags: php, data-structures, web-scraping, jquery-selectors, hidden-files

I am still beginner, I searched in Google but I didnt found what I want,

I have a website http://www.example.com/index.php

On the main page, there is selectio form:
e.g. one selects first country in first field, the the city in the second field then click the button to show the data.

I didnt find these urls of these data links in view-source, and when changing input from selection fields, the address still the same in browser.

How to get these links to these data, I expected in view-source as extension in website url so e.g. php?=city A etc...

Any help and what are these data protection?

**Edit**

that is part from view-source

```
/if (todo==9) window.open ('loadajax.php?ekey='+document.getElementById('embid').value+'&todo='+todo+'&mkey='+mkey+'&kkey='+kkey); $.post("loadajax.php", {todo:todo,ekey:document.getElementById('embid').value,mkey:mkey,kkey:kkey},function(result){ // alert (result); $('#'+id).html(result); }); }
```

Comment: Open the "Inspect" tool (Firebug, Chrome Inspector, F12 Devtools, whatever you have) and watch the "Network" tab.  Likely AJAX requests are being made to a back-end system.

Comment: Thank Kevin, I will do, I had no idea what is that, but I will follow your tips

Comment: Chrome Developer Tools Tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wcFnnxfA70g

Firefox Developer Tools Tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e1kAVK0RikY

Comment: And what you're going to be needing to do: figure out the values in the JavaScript you posted and give them to "loadajax.php" on the site, then parse that response for your data.

Comment: thank kevin for your tips

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of one of the below two:

1. Install fidder. This is a free and open source tool that provides you all the network traffic and the links that are navigated.
2. Your browsers debugger tool should help you. If you are using chrome or IE, click F12 that brings you developer tools. Switch to the network tab to see all the links you are navigating to in an application.

Comment: thank you Awanish, that helped me partially to reach what I wanted, alhough I am still beginner to find quicker methods, I can t vote up, I was suspended I think

Comment: You are welcome.. dont worry about upvoting.. happy to know that this helped you !!